# I/O bound by reads? Ways to optimize?

Tags: performance, io, sqlite

In SQLite, I am reading data from one database using `SELECT`, perform some modifications and write it to another database.

Looking at the output of `iotop`, the process performance (using one core only) is I/O bound (IO>80%, CPU<20%). Most of the action that I can see in `iotop` is going on under 'DISK READ', and only every now and then there is something shown under 'DISK WRITE'.

Is it likely that the process performance is bound by the `SELECT`/read transactions? Basically all performance related information for SQLite that I see on the web is about `INSERT`/write. Is there anything to know and optimize about reading data?

Could an inefficient query, i.e. by SELECT on a field with missing index have a stronger impact on IO than on CPU?

Comment: If you have many writes, you can optimize by merging them into one transaction. Optimizing reads is harder …

Comment: This question is way too broad. If you want to speed up specific queries, ask about those.

Comment: Consider putting the database you are reading from on a RAMdisk before you start.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That would be great, only I am afraid the file is too large (155GB file vs 192GB memory)...

Comment: What's your hardware?  If you're reading data from a single S-L-O-W 5,400 RPM SATA drive, you'll be lucky to get 50-60 IO ops/sec.  @MarkSetchell's comment about a RAMdisk is a specific implementation of the easiest way to run something faster:  run it on faster hardware.

Comment: I guess it's a normal server HDD, 10-15k RPM

Answer (score 0):

The question is fairly broad, so the answer is as well: Yes, selecting on a field with a missing index can have a strong impact on IO.

Depending on your query, schema, and data, SQLite may be performing a full table scan.

Running [explain query plan](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) can give you a good sense of what SQLite is doing in your particular circumstances.

Comment: Yes, however all relevant fields are indexed. Anymore ways to optimize?

Comment: It depends on your schema and queries. Explain Query Plan will tell you if your indexes are actually being used or not.